# Need to concat different value in multiple row in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

i am writing an after delete trigger, which should do
suppose :

```
2013
4023
4533
```

When Ever i delete a record last digit should be rebuild as

```
2012
4022
```

for this providing my psedocode:

```
i record;
SELECT Count(name) INTO v_CountTot FROM oca_shipmenttype WHERE oca_customerpo_id = old.oca_customerpo_id;

FOR i IN  (SELECT name FROM oca_shipmenttype WHERE oca_customerpo_id = old.oca_customerpo_id)
LOOP    
UPDATE oca_shipmenttype 
SET name = (concat(substring(i from 1 for 3),v_CountTot))
WHERE oca_shipmenttype_id = old.oca_shipmenttype_id;
END LOOP;
```

actually this code update all record with last transaction
as

```
4022

4022
```

Comment: what about this approach:-http://hastebin.com/unategobiz.pas

Comment: What when the old value was 2990 and the count is 3? What should be the after update value?

Comment: your approach is considerable , but after this i need to re sequence 3 digit as if suppose i delete 1 record 2013 then it should give 4012 and 4522

Comment: So, modify values so that the last digit becomes the row number. Looks like a variant on the gapless sequence renumbering on delete problem, and `row_number()` will be what you want for this too.

Comment: sir can u plz explain with example so that i know what should i do